# How to perform an equi-join on Geode with non-key column

Tags: gemfire, geode

Now I have 3 regions like below:
region1      ID, phone_number, name
region2      ID, credit_bill_number
region3      phone_number,  phone_bill_number

I know that I can join region1 and region2 by co-locating region2 with region1, and perform the query by using "ID" to join.

I'm wondering is there a way to perform a join on region1, region2, region3, which region1 join region2 by "ID" and region1 join region3 by "phone_number"?

Comment: If you join them like how you do it in SQL, what happened?

Comment: Because region3 wasn't colocated with region1 by phone_number, there's a situation region1 has an entry which phone_number is "0000" on server1, while region3 has "0000" on server2. In this case the query result is empty.

Answer (score 0):

All regions involved in a join must be colocated Partitioned Regions or Replicated Regions. Bottom line is, the data involved in the join must all be on the same JVM. If you can't figure out a way to write a PartitionResolver that forces the Region3 data to co-locate with the Region1 data then Region3 could be set up as a ReplicatedRegion, which would enable the join to work. Just make sure you mention Region1 first.